# Initializing UITextView based on the available text font size and font name

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

This is what i have tried,

```
 UITextView *_textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 10)];
    NSString *str = @"This is a test text view to check the auto increment of height of a text     view. This is only a test. The real data is something different.";
    _textView.text = str;


CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;//Here i am adjusting the textview

[self.view addSubview:_textView];



Basically after fitting the text into textview,scrolling is enable,but i cannot view the content inside the textview without scrolling the textview.I do want to initialize the UITextView frame size based on the text size,font name etc.
```

Any solution is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: even you want to disable scrolling?

Comment: @PKCoder. thats not primary goal,but still it will be good if i do that also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"This is a test text view to check the auto increment of height of a text     view. This is only a test. The real data is something different.";
UIFont * myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"your font Name"size:12];//specify your font details here
```

//then calculate the required height for the above text.

```
CGSize textviewSize = [str sizeWithFont:myFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

//initialize your textview based on the height you got from the above

```
UITextView *_textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, textviewSize.width, textviewSize.height)];
_textView.text = str;
[self.view addSubview:_textView];
```

And also you want to disable the scrolling in textview then refer this.

As William Jockusch states in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4652183/19679):

> You can disable almost all scrolling by putting the following method
>   into your UITextView subclass:
>
> ```
> - (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated {
>   // do nothing
> }
> ```
>
> The reason I say "almost" all scrolling is that even with the above,
>   it still accepts user scrolls. Though you could disable those by
>   setting self.scrollEnabled to NO.
>
> If you want to only disable some scrolls, then make an ivar, lets call
>   it acceptScrolls, to determine whether you want to allow scrolling or
>   not. Then your scrollRectToVisible method can look like this:
>
> ```
> - (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated {
>    if (self.acceptScrolls)
>      [super scrollRectToVisible: rect animated: animated];
> }
> ```

Comment: had missed something. .it worked like a charm now. .thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide proper citation when you copy the words of others. I've done this in your answer above, but make sure you do this in the future.